# Pseudo class selector for hover work fine in IE but not work in chrome [css]

Tags: css, hover, pseudo-class, checked, disabled-input

Here is the sample of my css code.

```
.step-radio-button:not(:disabled):not(:checked):hover + label {

    background: yellow;
}
```

I have tried change the :disabled to [DISABLED] or :enabled but it's still not work.

```
.step-radio-button:not([DISABLED]):not(:checked):hover + label {

    background: yellow;
}
```

OR

```
.step-radio-button:enabled:not(:checked):hover + label {

    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Works for me in Chrome 31 on XP: http://jsfiddle.net/5UbnL/

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Passerby. I tried to add one more label, it seem like not work with multiple adjacent siblings selector. Do you have any idea?
http://jsfiddle.net/5UbnL/1/

Comment: According to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators), `+` is used to combine two [_simple selectors_, which, do not contain combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#contents), so how two `+`s work is "undefined", and may not provide a consistance behavior across platforms.

Comment: @Passerby Thanks for your information. I have just found out the solution.
http://jsfiddle.net/5UbnL/2/
The issues are:
1. Browser version not up to date
2. Radio button hover not work with display none in Chrome
3. Chrome not support the siblings selector "+" together with pseudo classes

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble with this, why not simplify it?

```
.step-radio-button:hover + label {
    background: yellow;
}

.step-radio-button:disabled:hover + label,
.step-radio-button:checked:hover + label {
    background: <some_other_color>;
}
```